# If the probability per second of an event occuring is $1/2$, then doesn't that mean after $10$ seconds my is probability greater than $1$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For instance, if the probability per second for an event occurring, $p$, is $1/2 s^{-1}$, then to find the total probability of the event occurring in an interval of time, $dt$, is equal to $p~dt$. But if $dt = 10$ seconds then wouldn't I have a probability of $5$? I feel like I am confusing the concept of the mean number of events with probability here.

Comment: You are indeed confusing the mean number of events with the overall probability.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as you suspect.

The probability of a head is $1/2$. That doesn't make the probability of a head in two tosses $1$. The two tosses are independent. Now imagine you're making one toss per second.

Your probability of "$1/2$ per second" is similar but a little more subtle. It leads to a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) for the number of events in a time period.

Comment: Indeed, as such "$1/2$ per second" is not a probability, rather it is a *rate*.